# Scaling vertically with Redis

Tags: redis, memcached, scalability

Given that Redis is "mostly single threaded", I am wondering if there will be sufficient gain in scaling Redis vertically, versus something like Memcached (multi-threaded)?

Both can be scaled horizontally by adding additional nodes / instanced to a cluster. However, I am wondering if Memcached will have a more significant gain when it comes to scaling vertically because of the fact that it is multithreaded?

Answer (score 1):

Both system will allow you to scale vertically at a "very high" scale... but it is very hard to answer any sizing and behaviour question without having information about the application:

- size of the database/cache

  - number of keys and the size of the keys and the values
- the type of operations and the expected throughput and latency

For example as a very basic starting point you can go without any fear to a 25Gb Redis instance with a 25.000 operation/seconds with very low latency (<1ms)... *(but this wont probably be true if your values are 120Mb as the network will be widely impacted, but this is probably a very bad idea anyway)*

Also you have to take in consideration that Redis is a lot more than a simple key value store, with the various datatypes (String, Hash, Set/Sorted Set, ... and Streams) but also the persistence options, and modules that enrich the database for FullTextSearch/Indexing, Graph, TimeSeries, ...

You can easily run some benchmark against Redis using the ['Memtier Benchmark'](https://github.com/RedisLabs/memtier_benchmark).

So I do not thing it is a good approach to look at the issue from the "redis vs memcache" internals but to focus on your use case and dataset.

That said, [Redis 6.0](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/6.0/00-RELEASENOTES) has introduced a new threaded model for the I/O, that make Redis even faster than before.